# Can 'talia' modify a noun with an adjective?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, adjective

I want to say: 'such a strong group', and I'm thinking that this meaning of 'talia' found in the OLD can do this but in all of the examples none of the nouns are modified by an adjective.  Does this mean that 'talia' cannot modify nouns modified by adjectives?

Below the ~ stands for 'tal'

> 3 (pregnantly) Of such an exceptional (good, bad, etc.) sort of character, such (a).
> ▶ egon non defleam ~em adulescentem? PL. Capt. 140;
>
> nimi’ stulte facis, oculos corrumpis ~is Mer. 501;
>
> qui ‥ cinaedicus〈t〉, qui hoc ~e facere possiet? St. 769;
>
> gnatum ‥ ~i ingenio praeditum TER. An. 98;
>
> tantum laborem capere ob ~em filium! 870;
>
> illis ~ibus uiris ac tam amantibus mei CIC. Clu. 50;
>
> tene hoc, Atti, dicere, ~i prudentia ‥ praeditum! 84;
>
> hic tot et ~ium ciuium squalor Sest. 145;
>
> si esset quicquam cur placeret fratrem et ~em fratrem relinqui Att. 6.9.3;
>
> ~i ‥ tempore ludos facere 15.26.1;
>
> ut principes ~em nuntium attulisse ‥ uiderentur CAES. Civ. 1.53.2;
>
> tanton me crimine dignum duxisti et ~is uoluisti expendere poenas? VERG. A. 10.669;
>
> postquam cecidisse ~em uirum ‥ animaduertit LIV. 2.20.4;
>
> multis ‥ annis ~e consulum par non fuerat 24.9.7;
>
> nec bene famam eloquentiae Cicero ~i exitu pensauit TAC. Dial. 40.4; Ann. 14.53.

Glare, P. G. W. (Ed.). (2012). Oxford Latin Dictionary (Second Edition, Vol. I & II). Oxford: Oxford University Press.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to modify an adjective that modifies a noun, the word you need is ***tam*** instead of *talis*.

For example, *virgo tam pulchra* would be "such a pretty girl".
If you use *talis* instead, the girl is both "pretty" and "such".
The word *talis* only modifies nouns directly, so it can't be used for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that.